# Vue.js The list of mp3 files has already been stored in an array, but the sound still won't play

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I encountered a problem while coding and was able to fix it by searching the internet and making small adjustments to sample code. However, as I continued to add more lines of code, I came across parts that I did not fully understand but was still able to adjust to make them work. My goal is to create code that will play a sound to notify people who are waiting for service that it is their turn. The "filenames.value" variable already holds an array list of MP3 files, but I'm currently unable to get any sound to play.

: onMounted is called when there is no active component instance to be associated with. Lifecycle injection APIs can only be used during execution of setup(). If you are using async setup(), make sure to register lifecycle hooks before the first await statement.

```
<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted, computed } from 'vue';
import axios from 'axios';

const collection1Data = ref([]);
const collection2Data = ref([]);
const finalData = ref([]);
const latestfinalData = ref([]);

const fetchData = async () => {
  const [collection1Response, collection2Response] = await Promise.all([
    axios.get('https://koh-abx.com:50100/onboardshows'),
    axios.get('https://koh-abx.com:50100/onboardlands'),
  ]);
  collection1Data.value = collection1Response.data;
  collection2Data.value = collection2Response.data;
};

onMounted(async () => {
  await fetchData();
  setInterval(async () => {
    await fetchData();
    finalData.value = [];

    collection1Data.value.forEach(doc1 => {
      const matchingDoc = collection2Data.value.find(doc2 => doc1.idshow === doc2.idshow);
      if (matchingDoc) {
        finalData.value.push({
          idshow: doc1.idshow,
          numbershow: doc1.updatedAt > matchingDoc.updatedAt ? doc1.numbershow : matchingDoc.numbershow,
          ab: doc1.updatedAt > matchingDoc.updatedAt ? doc1.ab : matchingDoc.ab,
          updatedAt: doc1.updatedAt > matchingDoc.updatedAt ? doc1.updatedAt : matchingDoc.updatedAt
        });
      } else {
        finalData.value.push({
          idshow: doc1.idshow,
          numbershow: doc1.numbershow,
          ab: doc1.ab,
          updatedAt: doc1.updatedAt
        });
      }
    });

    collection2Data.value.forEach(doc2 => {
      if (!finalData.value.find(doc => doc.idshow === doc2.idshow)) {
        finalData.value.push({
          idshow: doc2.idshow,
          numbershow: doc2.numbershow,
          ab: doc2.ab,
          updatedAt: doc2.updatedAt
        });
      }
    });

    console.log(finalData.value);

    latestfinalData.value = finalData.value.filter(doc => (Date.now() - new Date(doc.updatedAt).getTime()) < 15000);
    console.log(latestfinalData.value);

    const filenames = computed(() => {
  return latestfinalData.value.map(item => {
    const digits = item.numbershow.toString().split('');
    return digits.map(digit => `https://koh-samui.com/sound/${digit}.mp3`);
  });
});

console.log(filenames.value);

const audioRef = ref(null);
const isPlaying = ref(false);

onMounted(() => {
  const sounds = filenames.value;

  let currentSound = 0;
  audioRef.value = new Audio(sounds[currentSound]);
  audioRef.value.addEventListener("ended", () => {
    isPlaying.value = false;
    currentSound++;
    if (currentSound < sounds.length) {
      audioRef.value.src = sounds[currentSound];
      audioRef.value.play();
    }
  });

  if (!isPlaying.value) {
    isPlaying.value = true;
    audioRef.value.play();
  }
});
    
}, 2000);
});

</script>
```

Below is the code that I try to change but still no sound come out

```
<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted, computed } from 'vue';
import axios from 'axios';

const collection1Data = ref([]);
const collection2Data = ref([]);
const finalData = ref([]);
const latestfinalData = ref([]);
const sounds = ref([]);
const audioRef = ref(null)
const isPlaying = ref(false)

const fetchData = async () => {
  const [collection1Response, collection2Response] = await Promise.all([
    axios.get('https://koh-abx.com:50100/onboardshows'),
    axios.get('https://koh-abx.com:50100/onboardlands'),
  ]);
  collection1Data.value = collection1Response.data;
  collection2Data.value = collection2Response.data;
};

onMounted(async () => {
  await fetchData();
  setInterval(() => {
    fetchData().then(() => {
      finalData.value = [];

      collection1Data.value.forEach(doc1 => {
        const matchingDoc = collection2Data.value.find(doc2 => doc1.idshow === doc2.idshow);
        if (matchingDoc) {
          finalData.value.push({
            idshow: doc1.idshow,
            numbershow: doc1.updatedAt > matchingDoc.updatedAt ? doc1.numbershow : matchingDoc.numbershow,
            ab: doc1.updatedAt > matchingDoc.updatedAt ? doc1.ab : matchingDoc.ab,
            updatedAt: doc1.updatedAt > matchingDoc.updatedAt ? doc1.updatedAt : matchingDoc.updatedAt
          });
        } else {
          finalData.value.push({
            idshow: doc1.idshow,
            numbershow: doc1.numbershow,
            ab: doc1.ab,
            updatedAt: doc1.updatedAt
          });
        }
      });
  
      collection2Data.value.forEach(doc2 => {
        if (!finalData.value.find(doc => doc.idshow === doc2.idshow)) {
          finalData.value.push({
            idshow: doc2.idshow,
            numbershow: doc2.numbershow,
            ab: doc2.ab,
            updatedAt: doc2.updatedAt
          });
        }
      });

      console.log(finalData.value);



  latestfinalData.value = finalData.value.filter(doc => (Date.now() - new Date(doc.updatedAt).getTime()) < 15000);
   console.log(latestfinalData.value);
   });

   const filenames = computed(() => {
      return latestfinalData.value.map(item => {
        const digits = item.numbershow.toString().split('');
        return digits.map(digit => `https://koh-abx.com/sound/${digit}.mp3`);
      });
    });

    console.log(filenames.value);
    sounds.value = filenames.value ;
    playSound();

  }, 5000);

});


const playSound = () => {
  let currentSound = 0;
  audioRef.value = new Audio(sounds.value[currentSound]);

  audioRef.value.addEventListener("ended", () => {
    isPlaying.value = false;
    currentSound++;
    if (currentSound < sounds.value.length) {
      audioRef.value.src = sounds.value[currentSound];
      audioRef.value.play();
    }
  });

  if (!isPlaying.value) {
    isPlaying.value = true;
    audioRef.value.play();
  }
};

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that the "onMounted" hook is called twice.
The first time it is called outside the range function and the second time it is called inside.
To fix this, you need to move the audioRef and isPlaying variables and the onMounted hook that references them out of the interval function.
So the hook is only registered once and the audioRef and isPlaying variables are accessible by both the interval function and the hook.

Here the code:

```
<script>
import { ref, onMounted, computed } from 'vue';
import axios from 'axios';

const setup = () => {
  // Define reactive references to store data from API requests
  const collection1Data = ref([]);
  const collection2Data = ref([]);
  const finalData = ref([]);
  const latestfinalData = ref([]);

  // Function to fetch data from two API endpoints
  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      // Use Promise.all to make concurrent API requests
      const [collection1Response, collection2Response] = await Promise.all([
        axios.get('https://koh-abx.com:50100/onboardshows'),
        axios.get('https://koh-abx.com:50100/onboardlands'),
      ]);
      // Update the reactive references with API response data
      collection1Data.value = collection1Response.data;
      collection2Data.value = collection2Response.data;
    } catch (error) {
      // Log any errors to the console
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  // Function to combine data from two API endpoints and filter unique values
  const combineData = () => {
    // Combine data from two API endpoints
    finalData.value = [...collection1Data.value, ...collection2Data.value];

    // Use Map to store unique data
    const uniqueData = new Map();
    finalData.value.forEach(doc => {
      const existingDoc = uniqueData.get(doc.idshow);
      if (existingDoc) {
        // If the document with the same idshow exists in the Map, update it with latest data
        uniqueData.set(doc.idshow, {
          idshow: doc.idshow,
          numbershow: existingDoc.updatedAt > doc.updatedAt ? existingDoc.numbershow : doc.numbershow,
          ab: existingDoc.updatedAt > doc.updatedAt ? existingDoc.ab : doc.ab,
          updatedAt: existingDoc.updatedAt > doc.updatedAt ? existingDoc.updatedAt : doc.updatedAt
        });
      } else {
        // If the document with the same idshow does not exist in the Map, add it
        uniqueData.set(doc.idshow, {
          idshow: doc.idshow,
          numbershow: doc.numbershow,
          ab: doc.ab,
          updatedAt: doc.updatedAt
        });
      }
    });

    // Convert Map values to an array
    finalData.value = [...uniqueData.values()];
    // Sort the array by updatedAt in descending order and store only the latest 10 items
    latestfinalData.value = finalData.value.sort((a, b) => a.updatedAt > b.updatedAt ? -1 : 1).slice(0, 10);
};

// Call the fetchData function on component mount
onMounted(fetchData);

// Use computed to watch for changes to collection1Data and collection2Data and call combineData
computed(() => {
 combineData();
});

return {
 collection1Data,
 collection2Data,
 finalData,
 latestfinalData,
 fetchData
 };
};

export default {
setup
};
</script>
```

I took the liberty of making some optimizations to the code

Comment: Hi  Riccardo Pirosu ,Thank you very much    Internal server error: [@vue/compiler-sfc] <script setup> cannot contain ES module exports. If you a
re using a previous version of <script setup>, please consult the updated RFC at https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/pull/22
7.

Comment: right, sorry for the oversight, I should have corrected that.